# ¿por que no me guarda los cambios en la base de datos?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estoy tratando de editar los datos de un usuario en la base de datos mediante el id del perfil donde 1 = Administrador y 2 = Usuario, el problema que tengo es que no me ejecuta el cambio en la base de datos.

Esta es la tabla que tengo en la base de datos que es el perfil del usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con este método obtengo los datos de la vista para ejecutar los cambios, todos los datos se modifican sin problema excepto por el idperfil del usuario:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Editar(Usuario usuario, FormCollection form, string Rol)
{
    var objEdit = db.Usuario.Where(x => x.Vigente == true && x.IdUsuario == usuario.IdUsuario).FirstOrDefault();

    try
    {
        if (objEdit != null)
        {
            objEdit.Nombre = usuario.Nombre;
            objEdit.Correo = usuario.Correo;
            objEdit.Rut = usuario.Rut;
            objEdit.IdEmpresa = 1;
            objEdit.FechaCreacion = objEdit.FechaCreacion;
            objEdit.UltimoLogin = objEdit.UltimoLogin;
            objEdit.IdBloqueo = 1;
            objEdit.Token = null;
            objEdit.Vigente = true;
            objEdit.UpdateEmpleado(usuario, Rol);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(usuario.Clave))
            {
                objEdit.Clave = CryproHelper.ComputeHash(usuario.Clave, CryproHelper.Supported_HA.SHA512, null);
            }

            UpdateModel(objEdit);

            if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Guardado");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No Guardo");
            }
        }

        return Json(new Response { IsSuccess = true, Result = objEdit }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new Response() { IsSuccess = false, Message = "No se pudo editar al usuario" });
    }
}
```

Este es el método donde se falla el cambio ya que según lo que veo al debuguear se realiza el cambio pero al momento de volver al controlador los cambios en este método no se guardan:

```
public UsuarioPerfil UpdateEmpleado(Usuario empleado, string rol)
{
    var usuario = db.UsuarioPerfil.Where(x => x.IdUsuario == empleado.IdUsuario).FirstOrDefault();

    usuario.Perfil.IdPerfil = Convert.ToInt32(rol);
    return usuario;
}
```

No puedo encontrar la falla ya que visual no me indica ningún error al guardar los cambios.